# VBA for each loop iteration returns empty value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to Excel VBA. I've learned Python and Ruby before so any analogy to these languages are welcome.

While I was working on For Each loop, I keep gets Empty value for each iteration. 
i.e,

```
Sub testfield()
Dim testEach As Range
Dim testRange As Range

Set testRange = Worksheets(2).Range("O2:O76")

For Each testEach In testRange.Cells
    MsgBox (testEach.Value)

Next
End Sub
```

`Range("O2:O76")`

When I run this code, `MsgBox` returns empty space and the debugger also says `testEach.Value is Empty`.

What did I do wrong? How do I get the values out of that iteration? 
I'm working on a project and it's driving me crazy. Please help me.

Comment: That simply means the Range("O2:O76") is empty on Sheet2.

Comment: It might be the problem that you have multiple workbooks open and the workbook is not set, so it will go with the active one, which is empty.

Comment: Oh damn it. You're right. I changed the sheet's name but I forgot it had different index. Thanks sktneer. Should I delete this post so it won't mislead others?

Comment: @Vinnie, Yeah that was just a test code and my big project's code had the same problem so maybe you're right about that - referring to the wrong workbook(sheet) range.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code (I replicated it in my Excel, it works fine). Most likely, the problem is in "Worksheets(2).Range("O2:O76")" - it might refer not to the place you intended. To avoid problems, refer to worksheet by name (rename it, for example, to "MySheet", and then use Worksheets("MySheet").Range("O2:O76")
You might do the same for the range: name it (say, "MyRange"), and then refer to it as Range("MyRange")

Comment: A minor additional point - you don't need to use "In testRange.Cells", it's enough to use "In testRange"

Comment: You're welcome. If you wish you may delete the question.

Comment: Thank you too, RADO. I'll delete this post in hours so that you can read my comment of gratitude.